# como uma imagem se adapta ao posicionamento de um elemento no css?

Tags: html5, css3

Estou construindo um projeto e tive que utilizar o css, que por sinal não é muito meu forte, e me deparei com a seguinte situação, o site precisa ser responsivo, porém quando fui colocar elementos dentro de uma div na qual a imagem não só precisa adaptar seu posicionamento como o tamanho, aconteceu a seguinte situação:

[image: abaixo o erro de posicionamento]

Acima, os elementos deveriam se conectar pois essa parte marrom simboliza uma tubulação e ficarem conectados independente do tamanho do dispositivo, e estourou a div como podem ver, o que sera que está acontecendo?

OBS: os elementos são imagens dividas em partes pois vou trabalhar com o DOM.

> **Segue o código html da página:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="bloco1" class="container">
        <h4 class="text-center" id="blc1">Bloco 1</h4>
        <img src="/img/caixa_vazio.png" alt="cisterna vazia" class="caixa">
        <img src="/img/bombas_off.png" alt="bombas off" class="bombas">
        <img src="/img/cisterna_vazio.png" alt="cisterna vazio" class="cisterna">
    </div>
    <div id="bloco2">
        <h4 class="text-center" id="blc2">Bloco 2</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **código do css aplicado:**

```
#bloco1{
    width: 410px;
    height: 400px;
    border: solid 5px rgb(64, 206, 250);
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: no-repeat url(/img/imagem_fundo.png);
    background-size: cover;

}

h4#blc1{
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px black;
    background-color: rgb(64, 206, 250);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#bloco2{
    position: relative;
    width: 410px;
    height: 400px;
    border: solid 5px rgb(64, 206, 250);
    margin: 20px 0px 10px 10px;
    display: inline-block;}

h4#blc2{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.caixa{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    left: 322px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.bombas{
    position:absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    left: 169.7px;
    top: 150px;
}

.cisterna{
    position:absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    left: 359px;
    top: 300px;
}

body{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Mande as imagens para poder testar o alinhamento em diferentes dispositivo. Use links do https://imgur.com/ ou outro dispositivo de compartilhamento de sua preferência.

Comment: baixe do meu drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WAuWv7bhb6G9jB0-JwG8QYa_4MQACCJ7/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solução do problema:

Resolvi o problema colocando a propriedade `position: sticky;`nas imagens com isso elas acompanharam a todo momento seu elemento pai que era a div, fiz algumas modificações para o projeto e meu código ficou assim:

OBS: Estou utilizando a view engine handlebars.

> #### Na página HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="bloco1" class="container">
        <h4 class="text-center" id="blc1">Bloco 1</h4>
        <div>
            <small hidden id="valor_caixa01">{{caixa}}</small>
            <img src="/img/caixa_vazio.png" id="caixa_foto01" class="caixa">
        </div>
        <div>
            <small hidden id="bomba_valor01">{{bomba}}</small>
            <img src="/img/bombas_off.png" id="bomba_foto01" class="bomba">
        </div>
        <div>
            <small hidden id="cisterna_valor01">{{cisterna}}</small>
            <img src="img/cisterna_vazio.png" id="cisterna_foto01" class="cisterna">
        </div>
        <div>
            <h6 id="temperatura01" class="temperatura">Temperatura: {{temperatura}}°C</h6>
            <h6 id="pressao01" class="pressao">Pressão: {{pressao}}</h6>
            <h6 id="createdAt01" class="createdAt">Data da Consulta: {{createdAt}}</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bloco2">
        <div class="container">
            <h4 class="text-center" id="blc2">Bloco 2</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> #### No conteúdo do CSS:

```
footer{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #343a40;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

#login.container{
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    background-color: #343a40;
    height: 250px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#monitor{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 250px;
}

#relatorio{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 200px 0px 0px 300px;
}

#bloco1{
    width: 430px;
    height: 520px;
    border: solid 5px rgb(0, 31, 167);
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: no-repeat url(/img/imagem_fundo.png);
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

h4#blc1{
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px black;
    background-color: rgb(0, 31, 167);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
}

#bloco2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 430px;
    height: 520px;
    border: solid 5px rgb(0, 31, 167);
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: no-repeat url(/img/imagem_fundo.png);
    background-size: auto;
    background-size: cover;
}

h4#blc2{
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px black;
    background-color: rgb(0, 31, 167);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.caixa{
    position: sticky;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 149px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.bomba{
    position: sticky;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: -75px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.cisterna{
    position: sticky;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-top: -110px;
}

.temperatura{
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 15pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pressao{
    font-size: 15pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.createdAt{
    font-size: 15pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```